# aligning the x,y position of box based on where the mouse is

Tags: javascript, jquery

there are couple of images in my webpage and I want to display a box (more information about image ) when the mouse visits the image. I also want that the box position be exactly where the mouse is and it moves with the mouse movement. this is my code but it does not work. the problem is in Firefox the box and mouse are aligned vertically (not horizontally) but in Chrome box and mouse are aligned horizontally(not vertically )

```
<div class="library_teaser_photo_class">
<div class="book_detail" style="display:block;visibility :hidden;position: fixed;">
<?php print $fields['field_library_writer']->content; ?> 
</div>
<?php print $fields['field_library_photo']->content; ?>
</div>
```

and this is jQuery code

```
var offsetX = 10;
var offsetY = 20;
$('.library_teaser_photo_class').hover(function(e)
{
if (e.pageX || e.pageY) 
    {
    posx = e.pageX;
    posy = e.pageY;
}
else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    
    {
     posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                          +   document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
     posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                          +document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
    $(this).find('.book_detail').css('visibility','visible')
                                .css('top',posy + offsetY)
                    .css('left',posx + offsetX);
},function(){
        $(this).find('.book_detail').css('visibility','hidden');
});

$('.library_teaser_photo_class').mousemove(function(e){
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
            {
          posx = e.pageX;
          posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) 
            {
    posx = e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft
                             +document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                             +document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
$(this).find('.book_detail').css('top',posy ).css('left',posx );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
       mouseX = e.pageX; 
       mouseY = e.pageY;
    });  
    $('.library_teaser_photo_class').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).find('.book_detail').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
    });


the function above will make the DIV appear over the link wherever that may be on the page. It will fade in slowly when the link is hovered. You could also use .hover() instead. From there the DIV will stay, so if you would like the DIV to disappear when the mouse moves away, then,

    $('.library_teaser_photo_class').mouseout(function(){
     $(this).find('.book_detail').fadeOut('slow');
    });

If you DIV is already positioned, you can simply use

    $('.library_teaser_photo_class').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('.book_detail').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

Also, keep in mind, your DIV style needs to be set to `display:none;` in order for it to fadeIn or show.